# остановка цикла for на python

Tags: python, рекурсия

```py
def find_key(box):
    for item  in box:
        print(item)
        if item ==0:
            continue
        elif item =="key":
            print("key finded")
            break
        else:
            find_key(item)


box_with_boxes=[
                [[["key"],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]]],
                [[[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]]],
                [[[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]]]
]

find_key(box_with_boxes)
```

Я пытаюсь убедиться, что после нахождения ключа цикл завершается полностью, я уже понял, что `break` - это не то, что мне нужно, я пробовал некоторые другие методы, но это не сработало. Я понимаю, как это сделать с помощью цикла `while`, но я хочу понять, как это работает с циклом `for`.

Comment: `break - это не то, что мне нужно`  - почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение через глобальную переменную:

```py
is_finded = False

def find_key(box):
    global is_finded

    for item  in box:
        if is_finded:
            return

        print(item)

        if item == 0:
            continue
        elif item == "key":
            print("key finded")
            is_finded = True
            return
        else:
            find_key(item)


box_with_boxes=[
                [[["key"],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]]],
                [[[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]]],
                [[[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]]]
]

find_key(box_with_boxes)
```

Comment: Зачем тут глобальная переменная?

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись и без глобальных переменных с помощью обычного `break`, который нужно вынести в конец цикла, локальной переменной проверки статуса обрабоки (здесь `check`), на которую `break` и завязываем. Если особо не причесывать код с проверкой типов, то можно так сделать:

```
def find_key(box):
    for item in box:
        print(item)
        if item == 0:
            check = False
        elif item == "key":
            print("key finded")
            check = True
        else:
            check = find_key(item)
        if check:
            break
    return check


box_with_boxes = [
    [[[0], [0], [0]],
     [[0], [0], [0]],
     [[0], [0], [0]]],
    [[[0], [0], [0]],
     [[0], ["key"], [0]],
     [[0], [0], [0]]],
    [[[0], [0], [0]],
     [[0], [0], [0]],
     [[0], [0], [0]]]
]


find_key(box_with_boxes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно изменить функцию добавив boolean и затем обратится к ней через loop:

```
def find_key(box):
    for item  in box:
        if item == 0:
            continue
        elif item == "key":
            print("key found")
            return True
        else:
            if find_key(item):
                return True
    return False

box_with_boxes=[
                [[["key"],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]]],
                [[[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]]],
                [[[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]],
                [[0],[0],[0]]]
]

for box in box_with_boxes:
    if find_key(box):
        break
```